# How to persist check box as checked using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a program where I am populating the check box, once I click on the submit button, I am inserting the data into DB and I want to retain the checkbox state as checked for the values that I have inserted, so that when a user logs in again he can see the items he has checked the previous time. This is my code

```
<?php
$accQry = "select * from brands";

$result1 = mysql_query($accQry, $db1->conn);

$i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result1)) {
    ?> 
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <label>  <input type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['brand_id']; ?>" name="chk1[]"   ><?php echo $row['brand_name']; ?></label>
    <?php $i++;
}
?>
```

This is the code to populate and I don't know how to go about it further.

Comment: Voting to close as unclear

Comment: This post doesn't hold much water. There's a lot of code missing here and what you wish to do *after* the fact.

Answer (score 0):

Checkbox has attribute checked, which should be set when you want to check it - [how checkbox works](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_checked)

Comment: I might be wrong but in my opinion the answer is clear enough.

Comment: as per my code , i have a array of check boxes ,  which will check all checkboxes by default , but thats not what i want . i want only those checkboxes to be checked which user selects

Comment: Yes, but I assume you store the infromation whether user has checked the checkbox somewhere in DB? If so you can use it to set the attribute checked on your checkbox right?